# Erro JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) no Databricks

Tags: python, data

Olá, estou tendo o seguinte erro ao tentar executar este trecho de código:

```
for entity_table in entities:
  print(f"\nProcessing entity table: {entity_table}\n")
  sink_path = f'abfss://XXX/XXX/{entity}/{entity_table}_v3/00/tables/XXX{entity_table}_v3_00'
  if entity == 'china':
    countries = ['cn']
  else:
    if'cn' in countries:
        countries.remove('cn')
  for country in countries:
    print(f"  Processing country: {country}")
    source_df = process_source_data(country, entity, entity_table)
    if source_df:
      print(f"  Successfully processed source data for country: {country}\n")
      source_dfs.append(source_df)
    else:
      print(f"  Failed to process source data for country: {country}\n")
      
  # Process the sink data ONCE for each entity
  sink_df = process_sink_data(entity_table)

  if sink_df:
    print(f"  Processing join operation for entity_table: {entity_table}")
    for s_df in source_dfs:
      # Join on country_source = country_sink
      joined_df = s_df.join(sink_df, s_df["country_source"] == sink_df["country_sink"], 'left_outer') \
        .select(s_df["country_source"], lit(entity).alias("entity"), lit(entity_table).alias("entity_table"), "count_source", "count_sink")
      
      status_df = joined_df.withColumn("status", when(joined_df["count_source"].isNull(), "source not found") \
        .when(joined_df["count_sink"].isNull(), "sink not found") \
        .when(joined_df["count_source"] == joined_df["count_sink"], "ok").otherwise("not ok"))
      final_dfs.append(status_df)
    print(f"  Join operation for {entity_table} completed successfully")
  else:
    print(f"  Failed to process sink data for entity_table: {entity_table}")
  source_dfs.clear()

else:
  for s_df in source_dfs:
    status_df = s_df.withColumn("count_sink", lit(None)).withColumn("entity_table", lit(entity_table)).withColumn("status", lit("sink not found"))
    final_dfs.append(status_df)
    print("Processing after loop logic completed.")
  source_dfs.clear()

# Union all the DataFrames in final_dfs to get a single DataFrame
combined_df = reduce(DataFrame.unionByName, final_dfs)
print('\nFinished Union of all dfs')

# Compute the difference
combined_df = combined_df.withColumn('difference_val', combined_df['count_source'] - combined_df['count_sink'])

# Compute the percentage
combined_df = combined_df.withColumn('percentage', (combined_df['difference_val'] / combined_df['count_source']) * 100)

# Format the percentage to 2 decimal places (you can adjust as needed)
combined_df = combined_df.withColumn('percentage_str', format_number('percentage', 4))

# Combine both values into the desired string format
combined_df = combined_df.withColumn('difference',
                   concat(combined_df['difference_val'],
                      lit(',the percentage of the difference is '),
                      combined_df['percentage_str'],
                      lit('%')))
print('Finished Difference Logic')

# Optionally drop the intermediate columns
combined_df = combined_df.drop('difference_val', 'percentage', 'percentage_str')

# Step 1: Ensure the columns are of the correct datatype
combined_df = combined_df.withColumn("count_source", col("count_source").cast("bigint"))
combined_df = combined_df.withColumn("count_sink", col("count_sink").cast("bigint"))
print('Finished Step 1')

# Step 2: Use the format_number function to apply formatting
combined_df = combined_df.withColumn('count_source', format_number('count_source', 0))
combined_df = combined_df.withColumn('count_sink', format_number('count_sink', 0))
print('Finished Step 2')

# Step 3: Replace commas with dots
combined_df = combined_df.withColumn('count_source', regexp_replace('count_source', ',', '.'))
combined_df = combined_df.withColumn('count_sink', regexp_replace('count_sink', ',', '.'))
print('Finished Step 3')

# Split the difference column into two parts: the number and the percentage
split_col = split(combined_df["difference"], ",")

# Format the numeric part (the first part of the split) and replace commas with dots
formatted_numeric = regexp_replace(format_number(split_col.getItem(0).cast("bigint"), 0), ',', '.')

# Concatenate the formatted number with the percentage part (the second part of the split)
combined_df = combined_df.withColumn('difference', concat_ws(", ", formatted_numeric, split_col.getItem(1)))
print('Finished Last DF')

try:
  display(combined_df)
  print("Final DataFrame displayed successfully.")
except Exception as e:
  print(f"Unexpected error while processing the final DataFrame: {e}")
print("\nScript Execution Completed.")
```

Passa um tempo, aparece o print de 'Finished Last DF', entretanto, na hora de dar o display no combined_df, se passa muito tempo e eu obtenho este erro:

> JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException)

O estranho é que nem sempre dá este erro, às vezes demora mas chega a executar o display. Já tentei usar o df.cache(), df.persist(), entre outros, porém não consigo ganho de performance.

Também já tentei a ideia de criar uma temp view com o combined_df, e executa sim mais rapido, porém na hora de fazer a query na view, ainda demora.

PS: o combined_df tem apenas 2 linhas com 7 colunas.
Alguém teria alguma sugestão?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.